# MigraDoc: How to add a blank page after a section on odd pages?

Tags: c#, migradoc

I want to create a PDF document for double-sided printing to save paper on an report.

On odd pages after the end of an section, there should be a blank page reading "This page is intentionally left blank.", such that the report can be split by chapters as needed.

Any hints how to do this?

Comment: The makers of MigraDoc assumed that readers are smart enough to see that blank pages were intentionally left blank without a written notice on the page. Would that be OK for you and your bosses?

Comment: yes. in my case this is enough. a message would have been a bonus ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MigraDoc creates blank pages as needed. Just indicate in the PageSetup that you are creating a double-sided layout.

The tricky part is adding the text "This page is intentionally left blank". I think I'd add that text with PDFsharp after rendering the page with MigraDoc. But I'd rather leave the page blank, assuming the reader is smart enough to realize it was left blank to get a double-sided layout.

Comment: you are right. there is the setting `document.DefaultPageSetup.SectionStart = BreakType.BreakOddPage;` which solves the issue of the blank page.